# Pytorch specific operation for the finding dimension wise mean for a list of tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a list of tensors, each of `300x1` dimensions and I need to find the mean and variance for each dimension based on the list. **How exactly this be achieved?**. I could make this work in numpy with numpy arrays, with the following code snippet:

```
for item in embeddingLists:    # embeddingLists is a list of lists
                               # item contains list of numpy arrays
    tempVal =  np.mean(np.array(item),axis=0)
    meanVects.append(tempVal)

    temVar = np.var(np.array(item),axis=0,ddof=1) 
    varVects.append(temVar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from pytorch discussion forum, I could solve the problem. [Link to discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-specific-operation-for-the-finding-dimension-wise-mean-for-a-list-of-tensors/61844)

The relevant code is:

```
for item in embeddingLists:       
    tempItem = [stuff.unsqueeze(0)  for stuff in item] #convert a 1x300 tensor
    coomn = torch.cat(tempItem)     # Convert to a 12x300 tensor        
    temMean = torch.mean(coomn,dim=0)
    meanVects.append(temMean)
    temVar = torch.var(coomn,dim=0)
    varVects.append(temVar)
```